# Intel XDK for iOS - screen orientation lock

Tags: ios, intel-xdk

I've built a small HTML game which I plan to export to iOS and I want to lock the orientation to landscape. I've selected orientation to landscape under build settings but that doesn't seem to lock the orientation. I've tried experimenting with the following code:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady(){
        intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation('landscape');
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();   
}
</script>
```

however I'm not sure if it's correct or where to put it in my index.html file. Could someone help me by telling what code is correct and where it would fit into my index.html file?

My full code (without the above statement) can be seen below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>Bounce Bounce Bear</title>

    <!-- Allow fullscreen mode on iOS devices. (These are Apple specific meta tags.) -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="256x256" href="icon-256.png" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />

    <!-- Chrome for Android web app tags -->
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="256x256" href="icon-256.png" />

    <!-- All margins and padding must be zero for the canvas to fill the screen. -->
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html, body {
            background: #000;
            color: #fff;
            overflow: hidden;
            touch-action: none;
            -ms-touch-action: none;
        }
        canvas {
            touch-action-delay: none;
            touch-action: none;
            -ms-touch-action: none;
        }
    </style>


</head> 

<body> 
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <div id="c2canvasdiv">
        <!-- The canvas the project will render to.  If you change its ID, don't forget to change the
        ID the runtime looks for in the jQuery events above (ready() and cr_sizeCanvas()). -->
        <canvas id="c2canvas" width="1024" height="768">
        <!-- This text is displayed if the visitor's browser does not support HTML5.
        You can change it, but it is a good idea to link to a description of a browser
        and provide some links to download some popular HTML5-compatible browsers. -->
        <h1>Your browser does not appear to support HTML5.  Try upgrading your browser to the latest version.  <a href="http://www.whatbrowser.org">What is a browser?</a>
        <br/><br/><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx">Microsoft Internet Explorer</a><br/>
        <a href="http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/">Mozilla Firefox</a <br/>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/">Google Chrome</a><br/>
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/safari/download/">Apple Safari</a><br/>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe">Google Chrome Frame for Internet Explorer</a><br/></h1>
    </canvas>
</div>

<!-- Construct 2 exported games require jQuery. -->
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>



<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- The runtime script.  You can rename it, but don't forget to rename the reference here as well.
This file will have been minified and obfuscated if you enabled "Minify script" during export. -->
<script src="c2runtime.js"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        cr_sizeCanvas(jQuery(window).width(), jQuery(window).height());
    });

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function ()
    {
        window["c2iscordova"] = true;

        // Create new runtime using the c2canvas
        cr_createRuntime("c2canvas");

        document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
            cr_setSuspended(true);
        }, false);

        document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
            cr_setSuspended(false);
        }, false);

    }, false);

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Just checked, this might be a bug, we are fixing it, will update you soon.

Comment: Thank you krisrak! I really appreciate it!